# How to pass local variable to Jquery.globalEval() utility

Tags: jquery

Here is my code --
I am creating string variable with multiple conditions in loop.

```
var condition = "";                
                for (var n = 0; n < numColValue.length; n++) {
                    $.each(numColValue[n], function (i, colValue) {
                        if (colValue !== null && colValue !== '' && colValue !== "") {
                            if (!isNaN(colValue)) {
                                condition += " (parseFloat(obj." + numColValue[n] + ") >= parseFloat(" + colValue + ")) &&";
                            } else {
                                condition += " (parseFloat(obj." + numColValue[n] + ") >= parseFloat(obj." + colValue + ")) &&";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

and now i want to evaluate condition using Jquery.globalEval()

```
var filter_result = MyArray.filter(function (obj) {
                    return $.globalEval(condition);
                });
```

but it gives error 'obj is not defined'

Comment: Don't use `eval`/`$.globalEval` as there is always a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: i have tried using Jquery.globalEval() also but same error